# Numerical Integration as Model for Nonlinear Fit

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting

I'm trying to do a fit for parameters of a function within an integral but I'm getting errors when I try and run it. Essentially I want the following fit to work out:

```
model[a_, b_, x_] := Sum[NIntegrate[totalνLayer[p, m] (a (1 - b^-p)),
                                   {p, 0.2, 10}], {m, x - .45, x + .45, .02}]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[a, b, x], {a,b}, x, Weights -> 1/errors^2]
```

Where `totalνLayer` is a function I defined earlier. I just want the fit values for `a` and `b` and their covariance matrix, but I'm clearly doing something wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

For those who care, all of the necessary code is below:

```
amp[x_] := 47.5111 - 1.79354 Abs[x]
μ[mrad_] := 5.449517720787487 Exp[-0.0693211022591832 Abs[mrad]]
σ[mrad_] := 1.7679270770338407 Exp[-0.12510841305113626 Abs[mrad]]
γ[x_] := 2.5587996836804026 Exp[-0.20766051151975093 Abs[x]] + 0.5696086481954964
ω[mrad_] := 7.63444841081276 Exp[-0.08637416159312404 Abs[mrad]]
lin[mrad_] := 0.9648001654360766 - 0.10434481940699446 Abs[mrad] + 0.003062473453032527 Abs[mrad]^2

crossSection[x_] := -600.089 + 1201.5577451256304 x - 1751.9101332336447` x^2 + 1899.988095515613` x^3 - 1556.709382526493` x^4 + 974.3641634962205` x^5 - 468.5129814014657` x^6 + 172.90071370757002` x^7 - 48.48328424613457` x^8 + 10.067733931487915` x^9 - 1.4558045159248463` x^10 + 0.1215353564558521` x^11 -0.00009554527467999401` x^12 - 0.001211849211458331` x^13 + 0.00009244381215772915` x^14 + 6.85533417357146`*^-6 x^15 - 1.3215490607411126`*^-6 x^16 - 1.213701585221995`*^-8 x^17 + 1.4963340473233928`*^-8 x^18 - 6.405376189932708`*^-10 x^19 - 1.3047056106410797`*^-10 x^20 + 2.0016864863803638`*^-11 x^21 - 1.2643359066392302`*^-12 x^22 + 4.036927989211094`*^-14 x^23 - 5.368234695690585`*^-16 x^24 + 214.8882519560799` x^-1 - 54.26505937368572` x^-2 + 9.480463574208194` x^-3 - 1.1135829819290948` x^-4 + 0.08354380635765371` x^-5 - 0.0036045838406917876` x^-6 + 0.0000678896567028218` x^-7
```

And the definition of `totalνLayer`:

```
totalνLayer[x_, mrad_] := .3*3.78*10^-5*810^2*5 (amp[mrad] Exp[-(x - μ[mrad])^2/(
                          2 σ[mrad]^2)] + lin[mrad] x + (amp[mrad] γ[mrad]^2)/(
                          4 (γ[mrad]^2/4 + (x - ω[mrad])^2)))/(
                          crossSection[x] 10^-38*1*6300*6.022*10^23)
```

And the data:

```
data = {{0, 1185.2847069383793`}, {4, 780.6026466248076`}, {8, 493.5502399832769`}, 
        {12, 312.1838499130911`}, {16, 193.16881196193143`}, {20, 113.41366552793787`},
        {24, 64.20654682074144`}};

errors = {132.12627600307064`, 90.55918065608893`, 60.884899393246535`,
         41.88064141772561`, 29.076284534300132`, 20.049728493077968`, 
         13.950371635495452`};
```

And last but not least the model and fit:

```
model[a_, b_, x_] := Sum[NIntegrate[
                           totalνLayer[p, m] (a (1 - b^-p))*10^-38*1.4*150*6.022*10^23,
                           {p, 0.2, 10}], 
                        {m, x - .45, x + .45, .02}]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[α, β, x], {α, β}, x, Weights -> 1/errors^2]
```

I apologize for all of the weird numbers and functions; this is neutrino data from my research.

Comment: Can't try it right now, but does it help when you change the model definition LHS to `model[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ,x_?NumericQ]` ?

Comment: I just tried it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

So, this isn't a very charming answer, and falls under the category of brute force and ignorance, (with a heavy dose of the latter).

The problem is that `NonlinearModelFit` appears to behave similarly to `FindMinimum` and `FindRoot`, where the function is initially evaluated with the parameters being symbolic.  The `Nintegrate` within your model requires that the parameters are evaluated numerically.  I'll let the more educated *Mathematica* users chime in here because the suggestion to replace model[a_,b_,x_] with `model[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ,x_]` should have worked if this were the only problem.

Here's my attempt to help you out and find an answer.  A little digging in your code makes me think that the values for the parameters *a* and *b* lie in the order of magnitude $10^{-1}$ and $10^0$, respectively.  I'm going to choose a = 0.2 and b = 2 and I get:

[image: first attempt]

Not too bad for a not-so-educated guess.  We can calculate the sum of squares

```
Total[(data[[All, 2]] - trial1[[All, 2]])^2]
(* 4771.29 *)
```

and use this as a starting point to improve our fit.  Evaulating the sum of squares at various points *a la*

```
out = Table[{a, b, Total[(data[[All, 2]] - 
  Evaluate[model[a, b, #] & /@ data[[All, 1]]])^2]}, 
  {a, 0.18, 0.22, 0.01}, {b, 1.8, 2.2, 0.1}]
ListPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[out], 3]]
```

[image: finding minimum]

I then search for the minimum:

```
Position[out, Min[Partition[Flatten[latest], 3][[All, 3]]]]
(* {{2,5,3}} *)
out[[2,5]]
(* {0.19, 2.2, 644.488} *)
```

So the brute force and ignorance approach is working.  A few more iterations and the best I've found is a = 0.185, b = 2.5 (sum squares = 95.7263), which gives us:

```
ListPlot[{data, {#, model[0.185, 2.5, #]} & /@ data[[All, 1]]},
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

[image: Best fit so far]

Parameter b needs to be optimized further since it is continually on the upper edge of the range that I search.  I fully expect one of the 10k+ rep guys to come in here and say "all you need to do is `Reap` `Sow` `HoldPattern`" and save you all this work, but I hope this exercise at least shows you one type of work around to get to the answer you are looking for.

And yes, I do know that you wanted a **weighted** least squares, but I have no idea how to do an *a priori* graphical weighted nonlinear least squares analysis.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for this! Do you have any ideas on how to use the errors and also somehow get a covariance matrix from this?

Comment: @feynmansafineman That's well beyond my statistics knowledge, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To "use the errors" you need to do the following:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

{r, t} = {8.31, 0.002};

data = {{1244, 0.90237}, {1289, 0.83072}, {1306, 0.76147}, {1360, 0.6094}, 
       {1388, 0.40952}, {1428, 0.29419}, {1488, 0.15592}, {1494, 0.11718},
       {1527, 0.09192}, {1537, 0.07757}, {1590, 0.04546},
       {1594, 0.04563}, {1654, 0.03229}, {1737, 0.01976}, {1740, 0.01949}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  data,
  {Exp[-a*tt^n*Exp[-(ea/(r*tt))]*t], 10^12 < a < 10^14, 
    27*10^4 < ea < 32*10^4, 
    0 < n < 0.9},
  {{a, 10^14}, {n, 0}, {ea, 30*10^4}},
 tt, Method -> "NMinimize"]

ErrorListPlot[{{{0, 1185.2847069383793`}, 
   ErrorBar[132.12627600307064`]}, {{4, 780.6026466248076`}, 
   ErrorBar[90.55918065608893`]}, {{8, 493.5502399832769`}, 
   ErrorBar[60.884899393246535`]}, {{12, 312.1838499130911`}, 
   ErrorBar[41.88064141772561`]}, {{16, 193.16881196193143`}, 
   ErrorBar[29.076284534300132`]}, {{20, 113.41366552793787`}, 
   ErrorBar[20.049728493077968`]}, {{24, 64.20654682074144`}, 
   ErrorBar[13.950371635495452`]}}, 
 Axes -> False]
```

Output:

> [image: Error Plot]

```
nlm["CovarianceMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

Output:

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \text{6.434561442695655$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-11} & -\text{3.901357230169781$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6} & -0.325294 \\
>  -\text{3.901357230169781$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-6} & 0.236838 & 19723. \\
>  -0.325294 & 19723. & 1.64449\times 10^9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$