# ParametricNDSolveValue::nlnum error in conjuction with NonlinearModelFit

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, warning-messages, nonlinear

I am trying to use ParametricNDSolveValue with NonlinearModelFit in order to fit a differential model to some data.  I am following the documentation here under Applications/Parameter Fitting: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html

The documentation example works great for me. The problem is when I use my own model and data, I keep getting an error message that seems strange and out of context to me:

```
testdata={{1, 0.00009548941732563731}, {101, 0.9234156316342383}, {201, 3.169678865642687}, 
  {301, 5.770066790545615}, {401, 8.007752270115398}, {501, 9.63764824871765}, 
  {601, 10.71272247965258}, {701, 11.380612793541024}, {801, 11.761472037816578}, 
  {901, 11.694455123303454}, {1001, 11.627820089304084}, {1101, 11.56156489420518}, 
  {1201, 11.495687246587122}, {1301, 11.430184947943506}, {1401, 11.365055874810842}, 
  {1501, 11.300297901728584}, {1601, 11.235908918183338}, {1701, 11.171886822658932}, 
  {1801, 11.108229526053263}, {1901, 11.044934960543287}, {2001, 10.982001044546381}, 
  {2101, 10.919425710642873}, {2201, 10.857206933289556}, {2301, 10.795342678813919}, 
  {2401, 10.73383091650653}, {2501, 10.672669644642585}, {2601, 10.611856874496073}, 
  {2701, 10.551390611711986}, {2801, 10.49126888326679}, {2901, 10.43148973333629}, 
  {3001, 10.372051202912106}, {3101, 10.312951353605266}, {3201, 10.254188257327602}, 
  {3301, 10.195759986157272}, {3401, 10.137664640143038}, {3501, 10.079900328269481}, 
  {3601, 10.022465159521184}, {3701, 9.965357246277472}, {3801, 9.90857473007318}, 
  {3901, 9.852115766465182}, {4001, 9.7959785110755}, {4101, 9.740161119622067}, 
  {4201, 9.684661766620447}, {4301, 9.629478652137225}, {4401, 9.574609977715335}, 
  {4501, 9.520053943251227}, {4601, 9.465808730076304}, {4701, 9.411872583200307}, 
  {4801, 9.35824376907317}, {4901, 9.304920554144836}, {5001, 9.251901204865241}, 
  {5101, 9.199183987684325}, {5201, 9.146767169052024}, {5301, 9.094649015418282}, 
  {5401, 9.042827793698757}, {5501, 8.991301804445536}, {5601, 8.940069395555765}, 
  {5701, 8.889128918137416}, {5801, 8.838478723298456}, {5901, 8.788117162146852}, 
  {6001, 8.738042585790575}, {6101, 8.688253345337593}, {6201, 8.638747791895874}, 
  {6301, 8.589524279233093}, {6401, 8.54058120545004}, {6501, 8.491917001537683}, 
  {6601, 8.443530099121851}, {6701, 8.395418929828384}, {6801, 8.347581925283112}, 
  {6901, 8.300017517111874}, {7001, 8.252724136940502}, {7101, 8.205700216394835}, 
  {7201, 8.158944194399854}, {7301, 8.112454560198403}, {7401, 8.066229821998448}, 
  {7501, 8.020268488014702}, {7601, 7.974569066461876}, {7701, 7.929130065554683}, 
  {7801, 7.883949993507835}, {7901, 7.839027358536044}, {8001, 7.794360668782631}, 
  {8101, 7.74994844766569}, {8201, 7.705789267384929}, {8301, 7.661881709002078}, 
  {8401, 7.61822435357887}, {8501, 7.574815782177037}, {8601, 7.53165457585831}, 
  {8701, 7.488739315684421}, {8801, 7.446068582717102}, {8901, 7.4036409616776115}, 
  {9001, 7.36145508077641}, {9101, 7.319509578949874}, {9201, 7.277803092077042}, 
  {9301, 7.236334256036951}, {9401, 7.195101706708642}, {9501, 7.1541040839964705}, 
  {9601, 7.113340057147644}, {9701, 7.072808307729679}, {9801, 7.032507517306886}, 
  {9901, 6.992436367443573}}
```

```
RL = 50.; 
Lk = 0.875*10^6; 
v0 = 0.06; 
Rsq = 461; 
width = 70; 
Iss = 1.04; 
δ = 1.*^-11; 
Ibn = 12.5; 
Nhs = 1; 
tch = Sqrt[(width*Lk*Iss)/(2*Sqrt[2]*v0*Rsq*Ibn)]; 
Rch = Lk/tch; 
δ = 1.*^-11; 
Clear[τr]
model = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {Derivative[1][Iread][t] == 
       R[t]*((Ibn - Iread[t])/(tch*Rch)) - Iread[t]/τr, 
     Derivative[1][R][t] == 
       Piecewise[
         {{(Rch/(tch*Ibn)) * 
           (((Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2) /
             Sqrt[((Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2*0.5 + Abs[(Ibn - Iread[t])^2  - 
                   Iss^2*0.5])/2. + δ]), 
           R[t] > 0}, 
          {0, 
           R[t] <= 0}}], 
      Iread[0] == 0, R[0] == 0.}, Iread, 
    {t, 0, 10000.}, τr]
fittest = FindFit[testdata, model[τr][t], τr, t]
```

Here is the (first) error it outputs:

> ParametricNDSolveValue, nlnum : The function value {5.86554*10^-9, 13.3632, 9.01097*10^-14, -2.9806*10^-18 - 0.0214555 (-3.46095*10^-17 - 3.46095*10^-17 (Abs')[155.709])} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {4} at {t\$1765520, NDSolve`Iread$25\$1[t$1765520], NDSolve`R\$109\$1[t\$1765520], NDSolve`Iread\$25\$2[t\$1765520], NDSolve`R\$73$2[t\$1765520], NDSolve`s\$1765597[t\$1765520], τr\$1765519} = {0.0000307256, 9.01111*10^-14, 0.000410594, 1.38438*10^-18, 0., -1, 1.}. >>

Because the error states "...not a list with dimensions {4}..." I was sure I was making some kind of syntax error, but as far as I can tell, my syntax is the same as in the documentation.  Is it just that my model is too complicated and for some reason this is the error message generated?

Thanks for putting up with my messy raw data and model — I tried to create a simpler version for posting here, but wasn't able to reproduce the error unless I used the full model.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Is `Ib ` supposed to be defined?

Answer (score 1):

<s>I found two issues. The first and minor one is that `Ib` is undefined. I am sure that this happened only in the course of copying the code to this site. If I set `Ib = 1` in my copy of the code, then at least `ParametricNDSolveValue` runs without any issues.</s>

When I call `FindFit` afterwards, it complains and sends me the same error message as yours. Note that `Abs'` appears in the errror message. The point is that `FindFit` tries to apply standard gradient-based techniques for finding the parameters with least squares error. But Mathematica does not know what the derivative of `Abs` should be (basically it was made so because `Abs` is not holomorphic). Replace `Abs` by `RealAbs` and this issue gets settled---only to produce another one (`ParametricNDSolveValue::smpf`). I guess we have to pass suitable `Method` settings to `NDSolve` in order to account for some discontinuities in the ODE but I have no idea how to do that. Maybe somebody else can tell how to fix that...

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  You are correct, Ib is defined in my notebook but just got left out with copy/paste.  I will fix it.  Good find with the Abs - hopefully I can do some more reading on this new error and figure it out.  (or someone with more knowledge than me will come along with some ideas :) )

Comment: Well, then just add the definition of `Ib` to the question so that visitors to the site don't get confused. I'll edit my answer, too, for taking that into account.

Comment: I'm still running MM 10, so I don't have `RealAbs`;  but here's a thought:  Is it possible to define a rule that sends `Abs'[x]` to `Sign[x]` throughout?    Or is that how `RealAbs` already behaves?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Sure, one can do `Abs' = Sign`. One can also use `Sqrt[x^2]` instead of `Abs`. Rounding off the corner is actually a good idea to help the optimization algorithm.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher:  It appears to work, too.  I'm writing up an answer now.

Comment: I take it back;  while "rounding off" the corners doesn't return an error, it doesn't return a very good fit, either.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Still, it might be interesting to see it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to arise because of the ill-definedness of `Abs[x]` near $x = 0$, particularly as regards its derivative.  We can try to get around this by "rounding off" the cusp of the function $|x|$ at $x = 0$:

```
eps = 0.01;
fakeAbs[x_] = Sqrt[x^2 + eps^2];
```

In the limit `eps -> 0`, the function `fakeAbs[x]` is equal to `Abs[x]`.  We can therefore try to run this code for various values of `eps`, and see if the values found by `NonLinearModelFit` seem to converge to any particular value.

```
fakemodel = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][Iread][t] == 
    R[t]*((Ibn - Iread[t])/(tch*Rch)) - Iread[t]/\[Tau]r, 
   Derivative[1][R][t] == 
    Piecewise[{{(Rch/(tch*Ib))*(((Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2)/
          Sqrt[((Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2*0.5 + 
               fakeAbs[(Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2*0.5])/
             2. + \[Delta]]), R[t] > 0}, {0, R[t] <= 0}}], 
   Iread[0] == 0, R[0] == 0.}, Iread, {t, 0, 10000.}, \[Tau]r]
fittest = FindFit[testdata, fakemodel[\[Tau]r][t], \[Tau]r, t]

(* {\[Tau]r -> 18.5261} *)
```

Reducing `eps` further does not seem to change the value of $\tau_r$.  However, it does not return a very good fit, either:

```
Show[ListPlot[testdata], Plot[{model[\[Tau]r /. fittest][x], fakemodel[\[Tau]r /. fittest][x]}, {x, 0, 10000}]]

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.204286} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >>
```

[image]

The `InterpolatingFunction` error comes from invoking the "real" model at this parameter value;  the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction` returned by `ParametricNDSolveValue` at this value of $\tau_r$ only appears to go out to about $10^{-6}$ or so.  It's also possible that I just used the wrong value of `Ib`;  I set it equal to 1, but perhaps this is way off.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  It seems we are definitely getting closer.  I fixed the error in the original post, but to fix your code just change any remaining "Ib" to "Ibn" or set "Ib=12.5".  I am actually able to get quite a good looking fit by fixing this mistake and giving the fit a starting point for tau_r: {tau_r, 17500}.  (Note this is the actual tau_r I used when making the test data.)  However, weirdly Mathematica throws a FindFit::sszero error.  edit: nevermind, the fitting algorithm is just giving up and setting tau_r to whatever I choose originally, not actually fitting.  Hence error.

Comment: @Kaquel The `sszero` as you've probably guessed is about the sum of squares being essentially zero.  It doesn't look like your "data" has any measurement error but only a bit of round-off error.  I have to believe that any "real" data won't have this minimal amount of error.  Might you consider adding a bit more random error in the simulated data?

Comment: @JimB thanks for the suggestion.  I have since tried adding various measurement errors between 1-10% and find similar results.

Comment: I have found a few things that help.  I found this thread - in particular the answer at the very bottom from Wolfram:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32455/findfit-for-a-differential-equation-model-with-multiple-variables
Comparing their solution to mine, I noticed they gave Mathematica some conditions in the FindFit function.  In particular, tau_r>0 seems to help a lot.  I am now able to give a starting value of tau_r=15000, and get a fit value of 16999.9.  (The "true" value is 17500.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but rather an extended comment.

Using @HenrikSchumacher 's suggestion of `Sqrt[x^2]` for `Abs[x]`, the following finds the "good" fit:

```
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Derivative[1][Iread][t] == 
     R[t]*((Ibn - Iread[t])/(tch*Rch)) - Iread[t]/τr, 
    Derivative[1][R][t] == 
     Piecewise[{{(Rch/(tch*Ibn))*(((Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2)/
           Sqrt[((Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2*0.5 + 
                Sqrt[((Ibn - Iread[t])^2 - Iss^2*0.5)^2])/
              2. + δ]), R[t] > 0}, {0, R[t] <= 0}}], 
    Iread[0] == 0, R[0] == 0.}, Iread, {t, 0, 10000.}, τr];

(* Mean square error function *)
mse[τr_] := 
  Mean[(testdata[[All, 2]] - (model[τr][#] & /@ 
        testdata[[All, 1]]))^2];

(* Find value of τr that minimizes mse *)
sol = FindMinimum[mse[τr], {{τr, 17000}}]
(* {4.2337870614665895`*^-16,{τr\[Rule]17499.999888098355`}} *)

(* Plot results *)
Show[ListPlot[testdata, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.02], Red}],
 Plot[model[τr /. sol[[2]]][t], {t, 1, 9901}]]
```

[image: Data and fit]

There are warnings:
[image: Warnings]

That `FindMinimum` seems to work and `FindFit` doesn't will hopefully suggest to others as to what the problem is.

(There also seems to be a local minimum at around $\tau_r = 250$ so a good starting value is essential.)